# Find duplicate 3D vertices from array

Tags: c++, algorithm, 3d, hashtable

I have an array of points. Each point has position(x, y, z) and normal vector (xn, yn, zn) , 6 double precision numbers in total. I need to find unique elements in this array and remove duplicate entries considering floating point tolerance.

What is the easy and efficient way to implement it?
I thought about constructing some space division structure like BSP or KD-Tree. But I think there should more optimal way like smart hash dictionary or something else.

So I'm seeking an advice which way to go and is there any lightweight C++ library that already implements it?

Comment: How about `std::set`?

Comment: @ZDF: "considering floating point tolerance"...

Comment: "considering floating point tolerance": that makes the result non-unique, I mean that `x-epsilon` and `x` are equivalent, so remove one of them, but with `x + epsilon`, we have `{x}` or `{x-epsilon, x+epsilon}` as possible output.

Comment: @Jarod42 Define your own comparison.

Comment: Yes, you can use `std::set` and define your custom comparison function for it.

Comment: How do you want to deal with the edge cases like four points in a square, where every point is a duplicate of two (but not three) others? Does it even matter for your use case?

Comment: note that std::set needs a transitive comparison though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing would be to round to nearest epsilon and bring the points into integer range (multiply everything by `1/epsilon`). Once they are integer hashes work just fine (`std::unordered_set`, `std::unordered_map`). This might miss some cases where 2 points are close but they round differently. You can overcome this by rounding both ways and considering collisions with either result.

If you use `std::set`/`std::map` note that they have log(N) access complexity (vs constant with hash versions). At this point you're equally good using BSP or KD-Tree (as long as you already have some library already implementing them).

Comment: Yeah, I think that will be a good solution, but since I have 6 coordinates and 6 possibly different round results I will need 2^6=64 hash tests for each point. But constructing BSP tree for irregularly distributed points, I think, will be much longer

Comment: You don't need to rounds all 6 parameters. I would only do it for the position (2^3 = 8 hash tests). You don't need to merge all the points you find so you can compare the normals after you've found neighboring points and decide then if you merge them or not.

Answer (score 1):

My implementation:

```
class VertexMap {
public:
  VertexMap(double tolerance): m_tolerance(tolerance), m_invTolerance(1 / tolerance), m_offset(m_tolerance * 0.1) {
    m_offset = m_tolerance * 0.1;
    m_offset2 = m_offset * 2.0;
  }
  void add(const MbFloatPoint3D &pos, const MbFloatVector3D &normal, const MbFloatPoint &texture, size_t index) {
    m_vertices.emplace(pos, normal, texture, index, m_invTolerance);
  }

  size_t findIndex(const MbFloatPoint3D &pos, const MbFloatVector3D &normal, const MbFloatPoint &texture) {
    auto vertex = Vertex(pos, normal, texture, 0, m_invTolerance);
    auto it = m_vertices.find(vertex);
    auto itEnd = m_vertices.end();
    if (it == itEnd) {
      vertex.pos.x -= m_offset;
      vertex.pos.y -= m_offset;
      vertex.pos.z -= m_offset;
      it = m_vertices.find(vertex); // (---)
      if (it == itEnd) {
        vertex.pos.x += m_offset2;
        it = m_vertices.find(vertex); // (+--)
        if (it != itEnd) {
          vertex.pos.y += m_offset2;
          it = m_vertices.find(vertex); // (++-)
          if (it != itEnd) {
            vertex.pos.x -= m_offset2;
            it = m_vertices.find(vertex); // (-+-)
            if (it != itEnd) {
              vertex.pos.z += m_offset2;
              it = m_vertices.find(vertex); // (-++)
              if (it != itEnd) {
                vertex.pos.y -= m_offset2;
                it = m_vertices.find(vertex); // (--+)
                if (it != itEnd) {
                  vertex.pos.x += m_offset2;
                  it = m_vertices.find(vertex); // (+-+)
                  if (it != itEnd) {
                    vertex.pos.y += m_offset2;
                    it = m_vertices.find(vertex); // (+++)
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    if (it != itEnd)
      return it->index;
    else
      return SIZE_MAX;
  }

private:
  class Vertex {
  public:
    Vertex(const MbFloatPoint3D &pos, const MbFloatVector3D &normal, const MbFloatPoint &texture, size_t index, double invTolerance):
        pos(pos), normal(normal),texture(texture), index(index) {
      normalizedx = pos.x * invTolerance;
      normalizedy = pos.y * invTolerance;
      normalizedz = pos.z * invTolerance;
    }
    MbFloatPoint3D pos;
    MbFloatVector3D normal;
    MbFloatPoint texture;
    size_t index;
    int64_t normalizedx;
    int64_t normalizedy;
    int64_t normalizedz;

    bool operator==(const Vertex &other) const {
      return Equalsd(pos, other.pos) && Equalsd(normal, other.normal) && Equalsd(texture, other.texture);
    }
  };

  struct VertexHasher
  {
      size_t operator()(const Vertex& k) const
      {
        size_t h1 = std::hash<int64_t>()(k.normalizedx);
        size_t h2 = std::hash<int64_t>()(k.normalizedy);
        size_t h3 = std::hash<int64_t>()(k.normalizedz);
        return (h1 ^ (h2 << 1)) ^ h3;
      }
  };

  double m_tolerance;
  double m_invTolerance;
  double m_offset;
  double m_offset2;
  std::unordered_set<Vertex, VertexHasher> m_vertices;
};
```